# Recursion: How to fix error "Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component."

Tags: react-native, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function to display a discussion (conversation and replies) tree.

```
export default class SocialPost extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  replies = data => {
    return data.map(item => {
      return <View key={item._id}>{this.individualPost(item)}</View>;
    });
  };

  individualPost = data => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{data.comment}</Text>
        </View>
        {data.replies.length && this.replies(data.replies)}
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return <View>{this.individualPost(this.props.data)}</View>;
  }
}

    data = [
      {
        replies: [
          {
            replies: [],
            _id: "5cb07bb28346d729a25dfc38",
            comment: "xyz"
          }
        ],
        _id: "5cb07b8a8346d729a25dfc37",
        comment: "abc"
      }
    ];
```

but I get this error instead: Invariant Violation: Text strings must be rendered within a  component.

What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: You are treating `data` as an object, but it is an array of objects. So try passing an object of that array to `individualPost()`

Comment: Does this only happen when `data.replies.length` is zero by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is probably on this line: `{data.replies.length && this.replies(data.replies)}`.

If `data.replies.length` is 0, the part after the `&&` will not be called. That means that React will attempt to render the string "0" there, which is not allowed outside of a `<Text>` component.

A solution would be to just do `{this.replies(data.replies)}`, and then return `null` from the `replies()` function when there are no replies.

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! I changed my code to `{!!data.replies.length && this.replies(data.replies)}` witch works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

data.comment doesn't exist on your first pass. Data is just an array, so react-native things you are trying to render something here w/o it existing. The error is telling you literally that only text can be rendered there. You are trying to render a data type.

```
individualPost = data => {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Text>{data.comment}</Text> //your problem
        </View>
        {data.replies.length && this.replies(data.replies)}
      </View>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Well, I think that I’ve not been clear enough. The array is the data source for a flatlist. <SocialPost /> renders in the flat list. In the component data is an object.

Comment: `<FlatList
        data={this.props.social.posts}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item._id}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View>{1 === 2 && <SocialPost data={item} />}</View>
        )}
      />`